# Display different panel on button click (MVC pattern)

Tags: java, mvc, gui, controller

I have to code a gui like this:

[image]

It's an homepage with a left menu and a changing right part, on button1 click form1 must be displayed, on button2 click form2 a so on.
Each form has its own button "ok" that would call a controller function which will save data entered by the user in a database (but it is not relevant).

My question is:
I know that according to MVC pattern user button click should call a controller function, so what would the controller do on button1 click?
There are 2 scenarios in my mind:

1) **Controller create** the form1 and then pass it to the homepage view which will just show it on the right.

2) Controller just call the appropriate method of the **Homepage view** which will **create** form1 and will show it.

EDIT: What i would know is: is it a job of the controller to create each view corresponding to the form and then pass it to the homepage view, or it just call a method of the homepage view which will create and display it?

Comment: Can you explain me why are you downvoting? If you downvote without any explanation how am I supposed to understand where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

button 1, button 2 and e.t.c. should act like navigation.
When you click on "button 1" it should redirect to Form 1 Controller.
When you click on "button 2" it should redirect to Form 2 Controller.

For each form I recommend use separate controller.

Comment: Maybe i've not explained myself very well, I want to know if it's a controller job to create each view corresponding to the form and then pass it to the homepage view, or it just call a method of the homepage view which will create and display it?
I added it to the main post.